# Concatenation of two arrays in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

How to concatenate two arrays into a single array in Objective-C?

Answer (score 53):

```
NSArray* newArray = [firstArray arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:secondArray];
```

Or using mutable array version just add to it all objects from another array:

```
[myMutableArray addObjectsFromArray:secondArray];
```

Answer (score 9):

With immutable arrays:

```c
NSArray *arr1 = @[@(1), @(2), @(3)];
NSArray *arr2 = @[@(4), @(5), @(6)];
NSArray *arr3 = [arr1 arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:arr2];
```

or adding onto a mutable array:

```c
NSArray *arr1 = @[@(1), @(2), @(3)];
NSArray *arr2 = @[@(4), @(5), @(6)];
NSMutableArray *arr3 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:arr1];

[arr3 addObjectsFromArray:arr2];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSSArray *theArrayIReallyWant = [oneArrayIDontReallyWant arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:otherArrayIDontReallyWant];
```

If you need to, *retain* `theArrayIReallyWant` so it stays in memory, just be sure to release it when you are done.
That by far is the easiest method :)